# Is it a way to correct Internet Explorer view of an absolute iframe?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe

I have an iframe used as an index file to hide a url of next website.

```
<iframe style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; " src="  http://..." width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

This all works in all known to me browsers instead of Internet Explorer (checked on 9). Is it a simple way to make it visible correctly?

Comment: Change `top:0px; left:0px;` to `margin: 0; padding:0; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0`.

Comment: @Mooseman top and bottom at same moment?

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski What do you mean?

Comment: @Mooseman i mean it's quirks mode if you set `width,height,top,bottom,left,right` at same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all mixing html attributes with css is nasty thing.

Anyway this should work flawlessly if you are looking for fullscreen iframe:

**CSS:**

```
/* notice you actually don't need absoulte positioning */
body,html,iframe {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
body,html {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  // add head, css
<body>
   <iframe src=""></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not that I've found. Instead, you would need to use JavaScript to monitor window size.

Or just use a regular frame:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page title</title>
  </head>
  <frameset rows="*">
    <frame src="http://..." />
  </frameset>
</html>
```